# Нужна ли указанная запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, и

*Выстрели-ка, напугаем его,*(**?**) *и он убежит.*
Нужна ли запятая после части "напугаем его"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Выстрели-ка, напугаем его, и он убежит.***

1. Запятая в предложенной записи нужна. Это ССП с тремя предложениями,  причем их взаимообусловенность не обозначена. В принципе можно оставить такое оформление.

Примечание. Союз И может являться замыкающим только для однородных членов, и тогда запятая не ставится.

2. Тем не менее предложение делится на две смысловые части, поэтому желательно это  как-то обозначить на письме и в устной речи. Можно предложить такой вариант:

***Выстрели-ка – напугаем его, он и убежит.***

Здесь тире обозначает причинно-следственные отношения. Запятая ставится, а союз И используется как усилительная частица.

Comment: Вопрос с подвохом. "Выстрели-ка" похоже на общее: *Выстрели-ка, [таким образом] напугаем его и он убежит.*

Comment: С новым годом, oleedd, что-то редко заходите. Я сначала тоже хотела предложить вариант с общей бессоюзной связью, но  он мне не понравился: Выстрели-ка: напугаем его и он убежит. Конечно двоеточие можно заменить тире, но тогда устанешь доказывать эту общую  связь. Это пункт 2(3) у Розенталя, но там во всех примерах двоеточие.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Comment: Взаимно! Что-то Розенталь в основном говорил о том, что встречается, но не о всём том, что может быть теоретически. Скорее всего, боялся брать на себя такую ответственность. В некотором роде это как реформирование, даже когда решение очевидно. Такое двоеточие поясняет то, что уже имеется, но не то, что лишь предлагается, как здесь, это как-то не по-русски.

Comment: У Розенталя пояснительное двоеточие имеет широкий спектр значений: пояснение как раскрытие темы, изъяснение, указание причины. Например, здесь. Выстрели-ка, а зачем? Далее  указывается (объясняется/поясняется) цель предлагаемого действия.  Главное для отсутствия запятой – это наличие объединяющего фактора (общего элемента). Вероятно, можно было бы дать общее теоретическое обоснование, но он обходится перечнем частных примеров. И это во всех темах. Почему?  Думаю, что общество того времени не было готово к такому изложению материала. А к чему оно сейчас готово – я вообще сказать затрудняюсь.

Comment: При таком двоеточии (когда указание причины) вопросы "зачем?", "с какой целью?" не подходят. Найдите хоть один такой пример Розенталя. В таких случаях всегда подходит вопрос "почему?". Кстати, союзы "потому что", "так как", "поскольку", которые предлагает подставить Розенталь, синонимичны — это не спроста. При раскрытии содержания подставляется "а именно", по информации Розенталя. Не знаю, какое двоеточие у вас при изъяснении.

Comment: Можно ПОЯСНИТЬ все: причину, цель, подробно рассказать о чем-то. Вы ищете частные варианты, в то время как термин ПОЯСНЕНИЕ надо понимать максимально обобщенно.  Вы ведь знаете СПП с придаточными изъяснительными. А при отсутствии изъяснительного союза ЧТО мы получаем БСП со значением изъяснения. А прямая речь? Почему после слов автора мы ставим двоеточие? Это всё то же значение изъяснения, то есть передача информации (слышу, вижу, говорю).

Comment: Вы можете оторваться от конкретного Розенталя и обобщить его? Мне показалось, что вы хотели сделать именно это.  Изучаем конкретику, обобщаем, применяем  сделанные выводы ко всей теме – это общая схема процесса познания во всех науках. Мы же дальше первого этапа в изучении правописания не двигаемся. Тем множество, а у нас всего три основных знака на письме, как и ограниченные интонационные возможности в устной речи. И другого Розенталя пока нет, да и откуда ему взяться.

Comment: Обобщаю: при причинном двоеточии всегда подходит вопрос "почему?". Другое — не по-русски.

Comment: Это верно для причинного двоеточия,  но  причинное двоеточие — только частная тема (в правилах  Розенталя – пункт 6),  а первые места другие темы занимают. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150.

Comment: При раскрытии содержания подставляется "а именно". В какой теме подходит вопрос "зачем?". Нет такого.

Comment: Например:  Она спросила: "Я хочу узнать: зачем вы приезжали?"   Вы знаете ответ: чтобы увидеть вас.

Comment: Здесь не подходит: *Вы знаете ответ (зачем / с какой целью знаете?): чтобы увидеть вас.* Вопрос должен быть синтаксическим. И там тире прямо просится, ведь "а именно" там не подходит, человек не стремится раскрывать содержание, так как другой, по его мнению, догадывается. Вот вы просто придумали, а получилось, что сложно, с тонкими нюансами.

Comment: Для вас старалась... Ладно, oleedd, не придирайтесь по мелочам. Ответьте лучше на новые вопросы, вроде интересные (с вариантами).

Comment: Ничего не вижу интересного.

Comment: Да по звучанию надо выбирать, там творительный звучит. У Розенталя примеры с именительным народные, какие-то сельские. Просто многие ставят галочку первому ответу, может, не понимают, зачем она. А вот про фразеологизм лучше ответьте. С одной стороны, "кому не лень" там как подлежащее, а с другой — в некоторой степени интонационно выделяется, потому что стоит не в конце. Прокомментировал там ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Перед ‟и он убежит” ставится тире, так как оно ставится при контрастах — неожиданная или резкая и значительная смена событий, эмоциональное потрясение или улучшение и т.д. [(тире в сложносочиненных)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135), но если контраст интонационно не подчеркивается, то ставится запятая.

Выстрели-ка и последующее предложение находится в целевых отношениях: предложение заменяется на ‟Выстрели-ка, затем что напугаем его и он убежит”. Поскольку цель это также причина, то пунктуация как при причинной связи после условно-главного предложения. [(Двоеточие в бессоюзном, пункт 6.)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150) Если кто-то сочтет эти рассуждения несколько натянутыми, то всякое может быть. Если кто-то захочет поспорить на темы: причина это или следствие, или цель, или всё вместе, или ничто из этого, то я не стану спорить.

В итоге: ‟Выстрели-ка: напугаем его и он убежит”, если контраст интонационно не подчеркивается, и ‟Выстрели-ка: напугаем его — и он убежит”, если контраст интонационно подчеркивается.

Comment: Найдите хоть один пример Розенталя, где подходит "зачем?"/"затем".

Comment: Таких предложений вообще практически не существует, их и придумать то сложно. Я, кстати, написал примечание в ответе о том, что не буду спорить.

Comment: Дело в том, что при таком двоеточии всегда подходит "почему?", а оно здесь не подходит.